# Rotation matrix formula derivation?

Tags: rotations

I would like to understand where to following formula for a 2-D rotation matrix is derived from:

$R =\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} \left(\begin{array}{cc} a^2-b^2 & 2ab\\ -2ab & a^2-b^2 \end{array}\right)$

I believe the answer is geometric and if it is, a picture would be nice.

Comment: What if $a=\cos t$ and $b=\sin t$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I would not like to bring sin and cos into this if possible.

Comment: To clarify, is this a matrix for a specific rotation?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well, $a$ may equal values greater than $1$ ...

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$ meant to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the unit vector

$$\vec u=\left(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right).$$

The rotation that applies $(1,0)$ to $\vec u$ and $(0,1)$ to a unit vector orthogonal to $\vec u$ is described by the matrix

$$R=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Applying the rotation twice, i.e. squaring the matrix gives

$$R^2=\frac1{a^2+b^2}\begin{bmatrix}a^2-b^2&2ab\\-2ab&a^2-b^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't disregard the remark of  Lord Shark the Unknown.

Comment: isn't the matrix applying the rotation to the "opposite" direction now? Seems like the minus on the element that is set to b should be on the RH upper corner, not LH lower corner.

Comment: @Tony: a matter of convention.